# View related commands in MVVM application

Tags: java, mvvm, javafx

I was inspired by article [Decouple the View and its behavior to create a testable UI](http://blog.buildpath.de/javafx-decouple-the-view-and-its-behavior-to-create-a-testable-ui) and wanna rework my JavaFX application with [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

[image: MVVM pattern]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC564167.png))</sub>
.

Ideally *View Model* should be *View*-independent and be testable as usual Java class. Also MVVM uses *Command* conseption to change View Model from View. So Command implementation is a part of View Model implementation and may be simply tested.

The questions is how Command should be implemented if it's result is a View changing? E.g. in View_1 I have a button after pressing on it a new View (e.g. View_2) should be created and shown. Should such Command be a part of a View and not be testable at all?

Comment: Without actually answering your question: have a look at [Reactive Modeling](https://youtu.be/y2mvLSzM1kg?t=33m14s). It's a paradigm to model and implement view changes (especially in JavaFX) used by Volkswagen Group Research.

Comment: @beatngu13 Frankly, haven't understood Volkswagen approach for creating UI. The presentation is too theoretical.

Comment: I agree that the presentation could be a bit clearer. If you're interested, ask a corresponding question and I'll explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think command could be testable. I'm not sure how exactly are you going to switch views, but AFAIK in JavaFX there is something like a Scene and Stage which is parent for scenes, is that right?

So in your command you pass the Stage as a dependency and on execution you set it a new scene.

And you can easily test it in unit tests - you can mock Stage and check if command passes correct scene to it.

I don't remember exact details of JavaFX but I would implement it like this:

```
class SwitchSceneCommand {
    protected Stage stage;
    protected Scene originalScene; // you can keep original scene if you want to have some undo-redo functionality
    protected Scene newScene;        

    public SwitchSceneCommand(Stage stage, Scene originalScene, Scene newScene)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.originalScene = originalScene;
        this.newScene = newScene;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
         this.stage.setScene(this.newScene);
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's exactly I try to avoid - testing pure visual UI components.